# Setting MongoDB authorization configuration in Python-Eve

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, eve

I am using Python-Eve with a MongoDB instance with authorization enabled, so I need to provide user/pass credentials in `settings.py` to properly initialize Python-Eve API.

If used the `MONGO_URI` global configuration setting, to declare the database endpoint as described [here](http://python-eve.org/config.html?highlight=mongo_uri) it works just right:

```
MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://<someuser>:<somepass>@<host>/<auth_db>'
```

But if I try to use the other possible way according to Eve documentation, which is to declare at settings.py, individual settings for each part or the URI, like this:

```
MONGO_HOST = <host>
MONGO_PORT = 27017
MONGO_DBNAME = <mongo_db>
MONGO_USERNAME = <someuser>
MONGO_PASSWORD = <somepass>
MONGO_AUTHDBNAME = <auth_db>
```

I get an error like the one below:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('saslStart', 1), ('mechanism', 'SCRAM-SHA-1'), ('autoAuthorize', 1), ('payload', Binary(b'n,,n=root,r=MzcxMTQ1MTM3MTExNDYwNg==', 0))]) on namespace testapp.$cmd failed: Authentication failed.
```

What is missing to make it work this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I figured out what was wrong to make it work. The auth database that is used to check credentials is the same as `MONGO_DBNAME`, not `MONGO_AUTH_DBNAME` value. So in my example the users must exist in the `<mongo_db>` database, not in the `<auth_db>` as I was expecting.

But then, what is the purpose of `MONGO_AUTHDBNAME` setting?

Answer (score 1):

`MONGO_AUTHDBNAME` is useful for some old MongoDB authentication schemes which are now deprecated. For more information see the [original pull request discussion](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/pull/642).