# Python Eve MONGO_DBNAME vs MONGO_AUTHDBNAME

Tags: python, eve

Eve's [global configuration docs](http://python-eve.org/config.html#global) mention `MONGO_AUTHDBNAME` and `MONGO_DBNAME` parameters.

I'd expect `MONGO_AUTHDBNAME` to be the database Eve checks provided authorization credentials against.  The analogous CL usage being:

```
mongo -u "user" -p  --authenticationDatabase "<MONGO_AUTHDBNAME>" --host x.x.x.x
```

I then expect the `MONGO_DBNAME` to be the database Eve orients the endpoints/collections from.  The analogous CL usage being:

```
mongo> use <MONGO_DBNAME>
```

So that `host:5000/endpoint` would refer to the `endpoint` collection within `MONGO_DBNAME`

However when I set `MONGO_DBNAME` to anything other than the database I need to authenticate from, accessing every endpoint fails with:

```
OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
```

So...

Is my understanding above correct?
Can `MONGO_DBNAME` and `MONGO_AUTHDBNAME` be different / do the credentials in `settings.py` have to have the authentication database be the same as the database you want the endpoints/collections oriented from?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870025/setting-mongodb-authorization-configuration-in-python-eve) question. In short, `MONGO_AUTHDBNAME` is used only in old MongoDB authentication schemes. So you need to have your users in the `MONGO_DBNAME` database to make it work.